# clevercloud rails deployment. How to configure env variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deploy my rails app in clever cloud. I have deploy several times on heroku, but clever cloud keeps failing my deployment. 
I check the log file and fund this:

```
application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!': Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
```

I've been reading about this problem and it seems to be generated in the .gitignore file, beacuse it ignores the secrets.yml file.  The thing is that I have my code in a private repository, so I don't care. I have not secrets.yml in the .gitignore file, but clever cloud keeps complaining about that.
I install the CLI provided by clever cloud and run clever ENV and it returns this:

```
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_PORT= ####
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_HOST=######
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_DB= ###############
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_PASSWORD=#############
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_USER=##############
```

I also try to put

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

in my config/environments/production.rb

But I have no results. So, any help?? Thank you!!

(keep in mind that I have not acces to system bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` environment variable, you need to set it in your application, via the "Environment variables" tab of your application's details in the Clever Cloud console, or by using `clever env set SECRET_KEY_BASE "<the secret stuff>"`.

If the secrets.yml is not in your .gitignore file, make sure you commited it.